# Are Action<T> and Func<T> passed as strong references?

Tags: c#, callback, strong-references

I have a Register Callback method on a Game class that objects can register a callback with for when the game is shutting down.

```
public void RegisterAsyncShutdownCallback(Func<Task> callback)
{
    if (this.asyncShutdownCallbacks.Contains(callback))
    {
        return;
    }

    this.asyncShutdownCallbacks.Add(callback);
}
```

When the game shuts down, i invoke the callbacks.

```
public virtual async Task ShutdownGame()
{
    var callbackTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var callback in this.asyncShutdownCallbacks)
    {
        callbackTasks.Add(callback());
    }

    // Invoke all of the asynchronous callbacks first.
    await Task.WhenAll(callbackTasks);
}
```

My question is, what if the owner of one of these callbacks becomes null, because the monster dies or the item was set to null etc. Am I holding a strong reference to the callback owner? If so, is it better practice to provide a unregister method or should I wrap them in a WeakReference?

The engine is using callbacks in place of events so I can perform async operations in player, monster, battle code etc. So a lot of my objects have this RegisterCallback style of method, and invokes callbacks when certain events happen within the object. If I am holding a strong reference, I'd prefer to hold a weak reference and self clean up rather than rely on objects properly unregistering. The engine provides an API that lets 3rd party users create plugins and register callbacks. I don't want to rely on the devs properly unregistering objects if I can control it within the engine itself.

Comment: Yes, they’re strong references, and weak reference does not sound appropriate at all. Remove callbacks when removing objects from the world instead, for example.

Comment: So I have to assume 3rd parties will unregister themselves properly from my code? I can add an interface to all my game objects that has a `Destroy()` method or something that allows it to unregister before it's set to null

Comment: So a monster dies – how does that happen? There must already be a way to remove it from the world; unregister callbacks as part of that.

Comment: Honestly I hadn't planned that far out. It makes sense to have a central place were objects registration to and unregistration is handled by

Comment: I'm still building out the underlying pieces and haven't got to the actual creation of game objects, so I guess it's time to start figuring that piece out :)

Comment: What happens if the dev registers an anonymous method?

Comment: Sounds like you need to work with pen and paper rather than coding. You start coding when you have a general design of the complete project - what are the different classes and their relations and responsibilities etc.